# Linking 2 EditText to global variable and button to make a phone call

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I'm trying to make an app that makes a call based off two `editText` calls.

The instances are `editText1` and `editText2`. Once filled out, they click add pin to phone. I am able to get it to go to the phone call but only:

```
*215*null*null
```

shows up.

So, my question is what am I doing wrong if I want to store whats typed in `edit Text1` to be stored in `firstNumber` and `editText2` to be stored in `secondNumber`?

Furthermore, how do I get the `#` character to display?

So, the result of what I want is:

```
*215*firstNumber*secondNumber#
```

to be displayed on phone call.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText firstNumber;
    EditText secondNumber;
    Button   btnAdd;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);


                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,
                    "before the call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:*215*" + firstNumber + "*" + secondNumber + "#" ));
                   startActivity(intent);
               } catch (Exception e) {


                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now that We have it complete using  this method `

```
            public void onClick(View v {
            try{
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

            String text= et.getEditableText().toString();
            String text2 =et2.getEditableText().toString();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:*215*" + text + "*" + text2 + "#"));
            startActivity(intent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

`What i want done is add the Pawn sign or the hash tag at the end of output. For example

*215*text*text2 followed by the hashtag or pawn sign #
but it totally just tosses it out the window after text2.

so at the moment what i get is *215*text*text2 what i want is *215*text*text2#

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`?

Comment: i removed it  from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much. I took a different route and it worked this way. everything else was the same from the question.

thanks again

public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

```
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

                String text= et.getEditableText().toString();
                String text2 =et2.getEditableText().toString();


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:*215*" + text + "*" + text2 + "#"));
                startActivity(intent);


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't post follow up questions as answers to your original question. Simply edit your question and update it. Regarding your problem, I'm not sure what you mean by _get the number sign to show_. Please elaborate a little more and I would be happy to help you. But please edit your question and don't post here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual text in EditText, you need to use:

```
firstNumber.getText().toString();
secondNumber.getText().toString();
```

EDIT: Use the `Uri.encode()` method to show the `#` symbol as well

```
String phoneNumber = firstNumber.getText().toString() + secondNumber.getText().toString() + "#";
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: now the app crashes. do i have to convert it from string to integer

Comment: Not necessarily. You should be able to use a string directly to call. But if you want to, I have added an edit.

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem or need more help.

Comment: i get it to compile and run and doesn't crash when i click button but it just displays my toast message. sadly it doesn't do what i need it to do

Comment: Check edit. The `Uri.encode()` method should do the trick. I was able to test it successfully on my device. Let me know if it doesn't work or if you need more help.